# How to open TIFF raster dataset and label together in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff

I'm very new at GIS and now I get a problem importing raster datasets into ArcMap.

I have a raster dataset from an open data source and after unpacking it I get these files

[image]

The problem is when I put the TIFF files into the ArcMap I only get a grayscale image without any value/label displayed.

[image]

So what do I need to do to get an image with the correct labels?

[image]

(Like this)

Comment: Looks like the raster values represent classes. You will need to change to a categorized symbology. Unless you were supplied with a symbology layer file, where you can import the symbology from, you will have to do it manually.

Comment: The output you are expecting is a classified raster. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/image-classification-using-spatial-analyst.htm#:~:text=In%20a%20supervised%20classification%2C%20the,statistical%20properties%20of%20the%20pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the [symbology of your raster layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/drawing-a-multiband-raster-dataset-as-an-rgb-composite.htm) from stretched to unique values.